# Hide Toggle Side Bar Button NavigationSplitView macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

In WWDC 2022, Apple introduced `NavigationSplitView`, an alternative to `NavigationView`. All are good before I get a problem: I don't know how to hide the toggle sidebar button.

**What I want (like the Mail app, no sidebar button):**

[image]

**My code & result (I didn't add any code about the sidebar button in my project):**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Int = 1
    @State private var search: String = ""
    
    @State private var columnVisibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.all
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            Sidebar(selection: $selection)
        } content: {
            Content(selection: $selection)
        } detail: {
            DetailView(selection: $selection)
        }
        .searchable(text: $search) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to hide it? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Maybe it is using a NavigationView, not a NavigationSplitView or NavigationStack. There are ways to hide the total toolbar. But I also did not find a way to hide the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now possible as of XCode Version 15.0 beta 6 (15A5219j).

To hide the 'Hide / Show Sidebar' button add `.toolbar(removing:)` with a `ToolbarDefaultItemKind` value of `.sidebarToggle` to your sidebar `View`:

```swift
NavigationSplitView(
  sidebar: {
    <#T##SomeSidebarView#>
      .toolbar(removing: .sidebarToggle)
  },
  detail: {
    <#T##SomeDetailView#>
  }
)
```

Comment: `.toolbar(removing: .sidebarToggle)` works to hide the toggle button but the functionality is still alive.  I can still hide sidebar by dragging the divider and cannot reopen it after hiding it. Is there a way to disable the functionality of hiding sidebar as well as hiding the toggle button?

Comment: @Pytan Apple hasn't exposed the method of the underlying `SplitViewDelegate` that disables the collapse of subviews to SwiftUI yet. Some people have got this working with the `SwiftUI-Introspect` package, but your mileage may vary. I would suggest putting in a feature request to the SwiftUI team in Feedback Assistant.

Comment: You can drag it out again to unhide it